# Swift dictionary and Optional interaction

Tags: swift

I have the following example:

```
var a = [String: String]() //    [:]
a["test"] = Optional<String>.some("some text") //    "some text"

type(of: a)  //    Dictionary<String, String>.Type

type(of: a["test"]!) //    String.Type
```

I wouldn't expect to be able to add an `Optional<String>` to a `Dictionary` which has it's type explicitly declared as `[String: String]`.

I checked it whether the `Dictionary` was bridged to `NSDictionary` with the `type(:of)` method, but it is not the case. Or `Optional`s are casted implicitly in the example above, or is there another reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`subscript` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2885650-subscript) of `Dictionary` is declared as

```
public subscript(key: Key) -> Value?
```

i.e. it takes and returns an *optional* value:

```
a[key] = Optional<Value>.some(value)
```

adds a key/value pair to the dictionary, and

```
a[key] = Optional<Value>.none // or: a[key] = nil
```

removes the key and its value (if present).

However, a non-optional is automatically wrapped into an optional
by the compiler if necessary, therefore adding a key/value pair
can be just written as

```
 a[key] = value
```

Applied to your case: In

```
a["test"] = Optional<String>.some("some text")
```

there is no cast/conversion at all, but in

```
a["test"] = "some text"
```

the string on the right-hand side is wrapped by the compiler into
an optional, so both assignments are identical.